# Help understanding a logical reasoning question

Tags: logic, problem-solving

I'm having trouble with a logic question and was hoping someone could help me out. The statement goes like this:

“If all the accused were innocent, some would be acquitted. No one was acquitted therefore all must be guilty.”

I have identified the following propositional variables:

[image]

Based on the statement, I think we can infer that if all the accused were innocent (A is true), then some would be acquitted (B is true). Additionally, the statement tells us that no one was acquitted (C is true), which means that B must be false. Finally, the statement concludes that all must be guilty (D is true).

I've tried creating a truth table to confirm my reasoning, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the C variable. Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out how to incorporate the C variable in my truth table? And am I on the right track with my reasoning?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The contradiction of "all the accused were innocent" is **not** "all the accused were guilty".  This problem highlights the distinction between the *opposite* of a statement and the *negation* of a statement.

Comment: So what would you change about the truth table?

Comment: @user2661923 This is another truth table: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/409596215697866773/1095810877963387133/1008715274574377040.png

Comment: I would abandon any attempt to use a truth table to analyze the problem.  A truth table is a tool used to analyze statements and their negations.  A truth table can not analyze the *opposite* of a statement.  The way to attack this problem is to prove that the assertion is false by providing a counter example.  For example, you can have two accused people, one innocent and one guilty.

Comment: @Bishop_1 Truth tables work with propositional logic, *not* predicate logic with quantifiers ($\exists,\forall$) like in this problem. So short answer is that you won't be able to solve it with truth tables.

Comment: Hint: "No one" = "It is not the case that some"

Comment: The argument is simply: $\forall x (Ac(x) \to I(x)) \to \exists x (Ac(x) \land Aq(x))$ and $\lnot \exists x (Ac(x) \land Aq(x))$. Therefore:  $\forall x (Ac(x) \to \lnot I(x))$.

Comment: Maybe we can simplify it omitting the $Ac$ predicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “If all the accused were innocent, some would be acquitted. No one was
> acquitted therefore all must be guilty.”
>
> [image]

For consistency with $C,$ you should change the 'are' in $B$ to 'was'. Or just rewrite $B$ as $\lnot C.$ The argument, clearer, is:

- If all the accused were innocent, some would be acquitted; no one was acquitted. Therefore, all must be guilty.

Using propositional logic, it means \begin{align}{}&A→B\\\text{and}\quad{}& C;\\\therefore\quad\quad {}&D.\tag1\end{align} If we allow quantifiers, then (here $x$ stands for accused persons):
\begin{align}{}&\forall x\;I(x)\to \exists x\;Q(x)\\\text{and}\quad{}&
\lnot\exists x\;Q(x);\\
\therefore\quad\quad{}&\forall x\;\lnot I(x).\tag2\end{align}

> [image]

You have correctly identified that $$C\equiv\lnot B,$$ but comparing columns 3 and 5 reveals that you are mistakenly believing that $$C\equiv D$$ (being acquited and being innocent are not synonyms!). Also, column 5 indicates that you are misreading column 6 as $$(A\to B)\land(\lnot B\to D)$$ rather than $$((A\to B)\land\lnot B))\to D.$$ Correcting your truth table will show that argument $(1)$ is not a tautology (its column is not all `T`).

Truth tables aren't able to handle the quantifiers in argument $(2),$ which is in fact **invalid**, since Gary but not Ivan being guilty makes its premises true but its conclusion false.